# List<> SIGSEGV on iPhone but not iPad in monotouch 5

Tags: list, xamarin.ios, ios5, segmentation-fault

I have a very weird issue in an app that was working rock solid in iOS 3/4.  It needs to preload a LIST<> out of a SQLite database and each item contains an int32 and a string.

There are about 36,000 items added to this list.  It has worked flawlessly on iOS 3.2 and iOS 4.3.  With iOS 5 out, it continues to work flawlessly on the iPad but SIGSEGV on an item add - about 680 elements in - but that varies between items 650 and 690 - it isn't consistent.

I have also updated XCode, mono, monotouch to 5, etc and rebuilt the App.  This issue continues to persist with failure on the iPhone, but rock solid in the iPad in iOS5.

Has something fundamentally changed in memory access in the iPhone relative to the iPad?  I have a hard time believing this is a monotouch issue since it runs fine on the iPad.  Any suggestions for how to work around this?

Comment: Which model(s) of iPads versus which model(s) of iPhones ? the amount of (physical) RAM between each of then will vary. Available (free) memory will also vary between the iOS version being installed, e.g.  are they all running iOS5 now versus iOS4.x before?

Comment: iPad1 and iPhone 4 and 4s.  The iPad 1 and iPhone4 worked solidly in 4.3, but with 5.0 the app dies in the iPhone.  Best I can determine is the garbage collector is running whacking the List<> while it is still being populated.

Comment: I doubt it's the GC, at least not wrt a List<>. Please fill a bug report at bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach the crash report and device log (you can mark them as private if you want).

Comment: If you can share your code with us, we can take a look at the crashlogs and pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you might try increasing the number of trampolines that monotouch allocates. There is some documentation here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/troubleshooting?highlight=trampolines#Ran_out_of_trampolines_of_type_0

I had an issue where I used a lot of generics and adding

-aot "nimt-trampolines=2048"

to the Additional mtouch arguments setting within the project's IPhone Build settings resolved the issues for me. If you add this setting, be sure to set it for each Configuration and Platform that you have configured.